# How to load classes automatically from new Jar added to Class path in java?

Tags: java, dynamic-class-loaders

I have two classes :

1. `MainClaz`
2. `MyTest2`

In `MainClaz` ,

```
public class MainClaz {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            try {

                Class aClass = Class.forName("com.test.MyTest2");
                Object t =  aClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception For MyTest2 ");
            }
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            try {
                Class aClass = Class.forName("com.test.MyTest3");
                Object t =  aClass.newInstance();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception For MyTest3 ");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have packaged both class in a jar (Jar 1) and put it to the class path .

Since `MyTest3` does not exist in this it will keep throwing `ClassNotFoundException`.

Now lets say ... I create new jar (Jar 2) containing class `MyTest3` and copy this jar to class path Folder.

Since I have put `MyTest3` class in different new jar in class , It should find `MyTest3` in class path on-wards but it is throwing `ClassNotFoundException` .

How can i make this to work ?

**Adding More information to Requirement :**

As of now class names are hard coded . But they would be read from external source (Let's say some database ). But I want is , add new class in new jar in class path , add entry of fully qualified name of class in database , so that in next iteration of loop program can dynamically load class .

Comment: You cannot dynamically modify the classpath of a already loaded classloader (the default class loader), at least I'm not aware of a way. To replace the default, you would need the JVM to restart. You can, however, create a new instance of a classloader, load the new class definitions in to the new class loader, and then use the new class loader to use the said class, please elaborate your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change package name of new jar to test2
2. Add an import for `MyTest3`:

```java
import com.test2.MyTest3;
```

Comment: Can you please have look to more information I have added !... see if that can add more to requirments